# error handling in nested bash scripts

Tags: bash, ubuntu, error-handling, bash-trap

I have a set of sh scripts:

```
Main.sh which calls - parent folder
      Sub-Main.sh which calls - child folder
             Sub-Sub-Main.sh  - grandchild folder
```

It is an installation procedure on Ubuntu.
I am currently do not have an error handling mechanism. I want to build a mechanism while every command in every script is executing and returning exit code different than 0 - to send the line that failed and to send me an email.
Something like: 'set -e', but with a function that is called when it happens and sends me the information by email.

I tried trap like that in trap.sh file:

```
trap.sh:    
    function exit_handler ()
    {
     Getting info and send email
    }
    trap exit_handler ERR
```

and at every script I made:

```
source '/folder/to/trapfile/trap.sh'
```

I run it like:

```
sudo bash Main.sh
```

and from the Main.sh I call:

```
cd /SubMainFolder
./Sub-Main.sh
```

and so on.

but it is not working. It doesn't get into the trap.
Can anyone advise with an example how to do it and on a good trap method to send an email with the error, the script name and the line failed ? Maybe I am not calling well the nested scripts ? maybe I have to put at the end of every script "return 0" ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you sure that ERR is the signal that you want to trap? How about distilling your code down to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can see the issue in action?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I want to do something like 'set -e' but with an event that when it happens, to send email with info.

Comment: Is it an option to make Main.sh not call, but source the Sub-Main.sh, which in turn sources Sub-Sub-Main.sh? That would simplify things considerably.

Comment: We can't really answer this question as it stands. It would be fairly easy for me to post an answer with example that works, but that won't help you understand why *your* code doesn't work. Undoubtedly, your code has something odd going on with it that we can't see unless you actually include it in your question. I'm submitting a close vote for now, but I will happily retract if if you update your question to include actual code that exhibits the problem.